# save name as an unique without change its current case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model

we have an issue for validation unique column creation

The problem is we have already one field name "Stack Overflow"

Now I am able to check if someone put "Stack Overflow" or "STACK OVERFLOW" or "stack overflow" we don't allow a user to create that field.

But when someone put more space between "Stack Overflow" it saves space it saves with that space so it doesn't check uniqueness of field.

we are using this code for unique column check

```
self.unique_columns = self.unique_columns + additional_unique_columns.each_line.collect(&:strip).map(&:downcase).uniq.select{|column| !self.unique_columns.map(&:downcase).include?(column.downcase)}
```

Can anyone suggest how we can check this type of scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen the answer but it was not solving the issue if we have name with space in front and last.

I have done it with `squish`

```
columns = self.unique_columns.map{|i| i.downcase.squish}
self.unique_columns = self.unique_columns + additional_unique_columns.each_line.collect(&:strip).select{|column| !columns.include?(column.downcase.squish)}
```

share if it could be other answer

Comment: Even though my answer will work.But, yeah, squish is the way to go for your usecase:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to replace any number of white spaces between two words with just one space to keep things consistent. Also, you can strip out all the leading and trailing whitespaces using [String#strip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-strip) method:

```
> 'Stack Overflow'.gsub(/\s+/, ' ').strip
# => "Stack Overflow"
> 'Stack   Overflow'.gsub(/\s+/, ' ').strip
# => "Stack Overflow"
> 'Stack        Overflow'.gsub(/\s+/, ' ').strip
# => "Stack Overflow"
> '    Stack        Overflow    '.gsub(/\s+/, ' ').strip
# => "Stack Overflow"
```

So, all of the above returns the same `Stack Overflow` string and can be considered as unique.

#### Update

As @Arv already mentioned, [squish](http://apidock.com/rails/String/squish) is the way to go to solve this problem as it will remove all whitespace on both ends of the string and then changing remaining consecutive whitespace groups into one space each.

Comment: I have seen this but it don't fix the issue if we have space in front and last of string, I have updated the code

Comment: In that case you can strip out the leading and trailing spaces too. See my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, but why should we do it when we can do it with squish?

Comment: yes, squish is definitely better solution for this purpose and you should use that. That did not come to my mind for some reason even though I used squish in my project before.